# implementing python metaclass for changing class level variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Can you explain, how to implement `AFactory` class for doing this.  It seems that I need to use metaclass but how? All my tries failed with `KeyError`

```
dct = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
}

class AFactory:
    pass

class A:
    NAME = ''
    VARIABLE = dct[NAME]

A1 = AFactory('key1')
a1 = A1()
assert a1.NAME == 'key1'
assert a1.VARIABLE == 'value1'

A2 = AFactory('key2')
a2 = A2()
assert a2.NAME == 'key2'
assert a2.VARIABLE == 'value2'
```

Comment: Why does `AFactory` have to be a metaclass? Can't it be a function instead?

Comment: ok, it can be function or simple class, but how to pass dynamically NAME in A class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you really want a class factory, not a metaclass. (Yes, metaclasses are also class factories, but they're not the only ones.) So the easiest solution is to define `AFactory` as a function:

```
def AFactory(name):
    class A:
        NAME = name
        VARIABLE = dct[NAME]

    return A
```

If you really need a metaclass, you [should implement an alternative constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52185979/1222951) rather than trying to make the metaclass callable as `AFactory(name)`:

```
class AFactory(type):
    @classmethod
    def make(mcs, name):
        clsname = 'A'
        bases = ()
        attrs = {
            'NAME': name,
            'VARIABLE': dct[name]
        }

        return mcs(clsname, bases, attrs)
```

Which you could then use like

```
A1 = AFactory.make('key1')
```