# What's the correct way to implement a metaclass with a different signature than `type`?

Tags: python, metaclass

Say I want to implement a metaclass that should serve as a class factory. But unlike the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) constructor, which takes 3 arguments, my metaclass should be callable without any arguments:

```
Cls1 = MyMeta()
Cls2 = MyMeta()
...
```

For this purpose I defined a custom [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method with no parameters:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super().__new__(cls, 'MyCls', (), {})
```

But the problem is that python automatically calls the [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method with the same arguments as the `__new__` method, so trying to call `MyMeta()` ends up throwing an exception:

```
TypeError: type.__init__() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

Which makes sense, since `type` can be called with 1 or 3 arguments. But what's the correct way to fix this? I see 3 (4?) options:

- I could add an empty `__init__` method to my metaclass, but since I'm not sure if `type.__init__` does anything important, this might not be a good idea.
- I could implement an `__init__` method that calls `super().__init__(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, vars(cls))`.
- I could use a meta-metaclass and override its `__call__` method, rather than messing with `__new__` and `__init__`.
- Bonus option: Maybe I shouldn't try to change the signature?

So my question is: Are the 3 solutions I listed correct or are there any subtle bugs hidden in them? Which solution is best (i.e. the most correct)?

Comment: 1. Is it required that your metaclass be a subclass of `type`? 2. Could you add a bit of background about the use-case for changing the signature (many metaclass use-cases are more recently possible using other approaches such as `__init_subclass__`)

Comment: @wim To be honest it's a rather theoretical question; I stumbled upon this problem while answering another SO question. So I don't really know how the metaclass was going to be used. But I do think there are some scenarios in which it would be useful for the class to be a subclass of `type`. So you can think of the scenario like this: I want to have a metaclass and an easy way to create instances of that metaclass (i.e. a class factory). If changing the class's signature isn't the correct way to do that, you can suggest a different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interface deviating from the parent signature is a [questionable design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in regular classes too.  You don't need the extra complexity of metaclasses to get into this kind of mess - you can cause the same new/init jumble by subclassing a `datetime` or whatever.

> I want to have a metaclass and an easy way to create instances of that metaclass.

The usual pattern in Python is to write a factory using a `from_something` classmethod.  To take the example of creating datetime instances from a different init signature, there is for example [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), but you have many other examples too (`dict.fromkeys`, `int.from_bytes`, `bytes.fromhex`...)

There is nothing specific to metaclasses here, so use the same pattern:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def from_no_args(cls, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = cls.__name__ + 'Instance'
        return cls(name, (), {})
```

Usage:

```
>>> class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
...     pass
... 
>>> B = MyMeta.from_no_args()
>>> C = MyMeta.from_no_args(name='C')
>>> A.__name__
'A'
>>> B.__name__
'MyMetaInstance'
>>> C.__name__
'C'
```

Comment: I'd say it's actually worse than just "questionable": Changing the signature prevents you from using the metaclass with the `class` statement, as `class Foo(metaclass=MyMeta):` will just throw an exception. So an alternative constructor is definitely the better solution.

Comment: Well, it is possible, but you would need to implement the cooperative inheritance correctly. Pretty much the same issue griped over in [super harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).

Comment: Sorry, what cooperative inheritance? There's no multiple inheritance here, is there?

Comment: Cooperative inheritance is independent of multiple inheritance. It just means that all involved classes have to *cooperate* to ensure `super` is used correctly.

Comment: ^ this.  If you're changing signatures, you're obliged to accept `*args` and `**kwargs`.  If you accept `*args` and `**kwargs`, *everybody* has to accept `*args` and `**kwargs`.